# running bash script from python fails due to missing program

Tags: python, bash, gcloud

running a script from the terminal:

```
(my_venv) ➜  my_directory bash ../../Framework/deploy_scripts/my_script.sh production
env is production
username on localhost is my_user
user in remote server is jenkins
copying everything by jenkins User from jenkins01
working....
```

now I attempt to do this via `python` from the same directory

```
os.system('bash ../../Framework/deploy_scripts/my_script.sh ' + env)
getting 
env is production
username on localhost is my_user
user in remote server is jenkins
copying everything by jenkins User from jenkins01
/scripts_directory/utility_functions.sh: line 92: gcloud: command not found
```

gcloud is a program I use . don't understand why gcloud is not defined

edit :
Tried

```
which gcloud                                                                          
/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
```

again, when I run it directly it works, from python - not working.

so both lines :

```
/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute copy-files --zone "$ZONE" "$USER@$SERVER_NAME":"$REMOTE_DIR_LOCATION" "$LOCAL_DIR_LOCATION"
```

and

```
 gcloud compute copy-files --zone "$ZONE" "$USER@$SERVER_NAME":"$REMOTE_DIR_LOCATION" "$LOCAL_DIR_LOCATION"
```

are not working for me.

The error with `/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` is different

```
 File "/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/third_party/argparse/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    import copy as _copy
ImportError: No module named copy
```

Comment: Is `gcloud` in your PATH, or is it a local binary?

Comment: `whereis gcloud` and use the absolute path for it. That or you need to start passing global variables around or make it so that gcloud is in the PATH that python has access to (which can become an issue if you use subprocess etc)

Comment: I'd add the `env` command to `my_script.sh` and see what the differences are, this will point you at where it's happening.

Comment: @SimonFraser , added `printenv` and there is no diff between the two ways.

Comment: @WebQube Ok and if you modify `/scripts_directory/utility_functions.sh` - `@line92` to use `/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` instead as it's binary path, does that solve the issue?

Comment: @WebQube also please show us the relevant code around line 92 of `scripts_directory/utility_functions.sh` because that's where things are failing.

Comment: @Torxed added in the question. not working from python

Comment: @WebQube How are you executing `scripts_directory/utility_functions.sh` and what does it look like `@line 92` ? I'm guessing subprocess?

Comment: Added it to question

Comment: It looks like your `google-cloud-sdk` environment is not being inherited when run through `os.system`, so you could try calling it explicitly, perhaps?

Comment: @SimonFraser explicitly from python how exactly?

Comment: How do you normally set up the environment for it? (I've not used it in ages, so can't remember)

Answer (score 2):

A quote from the [Python manual on **os.system**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> The **subprocess** module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes

Here's an example on how you could convert your script:

```
import shlex, os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = '/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud'
params = 'compute copy-files --zone "$ZONE" "$USER@$SERVER_NAME":"$REMOTE_DIR_LOCATION" "$LOCAL_DIR_LOCATION"'
proc = Popen([cmd] + shlex.split(params), shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, env=os.environ())

while proc.poll() is None: # If it's None, it means it haven't finished running.
    print(proc.stdout.read()) # while process is running, output anything it gives.

proc.stdout.close() # Never forget to close your open filehandles!
```

`env=os.environ()` is where you might add additional paths needed to run your scripts. You could even add `/Users/my_user/google-cloud-sdk/bin` to `env=...` only for this script and not add it to your computers global path variable, if you wanted to.